# Create DataSet From JDBC Source in Flink using Scala

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-flink

I am trying to create a dataset from a JDBC source using Scala in Flink, all the docs / other SO questions seem to use Java. I'm having some issues with generic types.

So far I have:

```
val inputFormat = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                 .setDrivername(driver)
                 .setDBUrl(url)
                 .setUsername(username)
                 .setPassword(password)
                 .setQuery("select col_a,col_b from my_table")
                 .finish()

 env.createInput(inputFormat)
```

This gives an error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[?0]
                    env.createInput(inputFormat)
```

I also tried

```scala
var tuple = ("",0)
inputFormat.nextRecord(tuple)
```

Which gave the error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int)
 required: ?0
```

And finally I tried:

```scala
inputFormat.nextRecord(_)
```

Which resulted in:

```
found   : x$1.type (with underlying type ?0)
 required: ?0
```

So the question is how do I set up a JDBC connection in Flink using Scala / where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixing the first issue:

```
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[?0]
                    env.createInput(inputFormat)
```

you need to add the following import statement

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
```

Comment: That did not solve the error. I am in Zeppelin, so that may be adding a degree of complexity.  Other thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zeppelin. Maybe ask on their users mailing list?